# merging 2 JS together problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 pages that uses JS.  1 is for a FULL PAGE and slide effect and 1 is to add a jquery audio player.

Both page work well independently...

Below is the code for each page

FULL PAGE HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- FULL PAGE include JS  -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>

<!-- FULL PAGE include CSS   -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b'],
            anchors: ['firstPage'],
            slidesNavigation: true,
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
        });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <p>Listen to our Music for FREE...<br>and download any MP3 as a VIP Member</p><br>
        <div id="includedContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

SECOND PAGE : AUDIO JQUERY that works

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/demo.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jquery-jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/ttw-music-player-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/myplaylist.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id tortor nisi. Aenean sodales diam ac lacus elementum scelerisque. Suspendisse a dui vitae lacus faucibus venenatis vel id nisl. Proin orci ante, ultricies nec interdum at, iaculis venenatis nulla. ';

        $('#includedContent').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay:false, 
            description:description,
            currencySymbol:'',
            buyText:'DOWNLOAD',
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath:'plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="includedContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

MY PROBLEM... I need to merge them together.. I need my jquery player to appear where I place a DIV in my #section1 of my FULL PAGE website and when I combine the code, it's not working. I know it has to do with some JS that I include that conflict with each other... but I don't know how to diagnose the problem and how to start looking for a solution.

I'm also not sure if my 2 code section for 
        $(document).ready(function(){
is done correctly?

Here is my HTML of my MERGE HTML of both... but it's not working.

Thanks.

HTML of combine code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- FULL PAGE CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />

<!-- FULL PAGE JS -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>


<!-- AUDIO PLAYER CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/css/demo.css">


<!-- AUDIO PLAYER JS  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jquery-jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/ttw-music-player-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/myplaylist.js"></script>    


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#f5f5f5', '#7BAABE', '#1bbc9b', '#ccddff', '#f5f5f5'],
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', '5thpage', '6thpage', 'lastPage'],
            menu: '#menu',
            slidesNavigation: true,
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right',
        });
});
</script>


<!-- audio player script  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id tortor nisi. Aenean sodales diam ac lacus elementum scelerisque. Suspendisse a dui vitae lacus faucibus venenatis vel id nisl. Proin orci ante, ultricies nec interdum at, iaculis venenatis nulla. ';

        $('#includedContent').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay:false, 
            description:description,
            currencySymbol:'',
            buyText:'DOWNLOAD',
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath:'plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
            }
        });


    });
</script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <p>Listen to our Music for FREE...<br>and download any MP3 as a VIP Member</p><br>
        <div id="includedContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you post a question, can you elaborate on the core issue beyond "it is not working".  What is the symptom?  What are you expecting to see that you are not seeing?

Comment: only include jQuery library once, **before all plugins and dependent code**. Your second instance wipes out the first and therefore any plugins that got referenced to first version

Comment: "It's not working". What's not working? Are you getting errors? Just looking at the merged HTML, I see two versions of jQuery included. You might be helped by reducing the amount of code needed to recreate the error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a help page that might help you.